# Show list with unique items from two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to create a list of tags based on my recipe-resource in my angular application.

This is my data:

```
[
    {
        title: "meatballs",
        tags: [
           {
               name: "meat"
           },
           {
               name: "pasta"
           }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "Seabass",
        tags: [
           {
               name: "fish"
           },
           {
               name: "pasta"
           }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I show a list with unique tags from this two-dimensional array?

Something like

```
<div ng-repeat="recipe in recipes | unique:tags:name">
    <div ng-repeat="tag in recipe">{{ tag.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
meat
pasta
fish
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to have an array for storing the tags (e.g. `$scope.tags = []`).

Then just iterate through all unique values and add them to `$scope.tags` if they aren't already there.

## **[Here's an example...](http://plnkr.co/edit/2zFuIsqrlHtW1rFRRY9i)**

JS:

```
$scope.tags = [];
var data = [
    {
        title: "meatballs",
        tags: [{name: "meat"},{name: "pasta"}]
    },
    {
        title: "Seabass",
        tags: [{name: "fish"},{name: "pasta"}]
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var current = data[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < current.tags.length; j++) {
        var tag = current.tags[j].name;
        if ($scope.tags.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
            $scope.tags.push(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this solution is when I remove a tag from the recipe-resource it still exists in the tag-list. So I need to update the tag-list each time I remove a tag

Comment: You could set up a $scope.$watch() and export the loop to a function. I know it's not ideal but that would work.

Comment: That will do I guess :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For array manipulation like this I really like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten).

```
var data = []; // your data

var out = _.chain(data).map(function (value) {
  return value.tags;
}).flatten().pluck("name").uniq().value();
```

Basically, get the tag arrays, flatten the results, pluck the name attribute into an array, remove the duplicates, and return the results.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, after you receive the data from `recipe-resource`, write a filter:

```
$scope.tags = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
    for (var t=0; t<data[i].tags.length; ++t)
        $scope.tags[data[i].tags[t].name] = true;
```

Then use a one-line div to display them:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{ tag }}</div>
```